# jQueryUI accordion - can I have more than one per page?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm very new to jQuery, but have found the accordion widget and have it working for the most part. My question is, is it possible to have more than one accordion on a page? I have several lists that need to be visually separate, and each needs to be its own self-contained accordion.

Here's my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function(){

        // Accordion
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            header: "h3"
        });

    });
</script> 
<style> 
.demoHeaders { margin-top: 2em; }
</style> 

<!-- Accordion --> 
<h2 class="demoHeaders">Accordion</h2> 
<div id="accordion"> 
    <div> 
    <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3> 
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div> 
    </div> 
    <div> 
    <h3><a href="#">Second</a></h3> 
        <div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div> 
    </div> 
    <div> 
    <h3><a href="#">Third</a></h3> 
        <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

What I need is to have a duplicate of the entire Accordion div with different content. How can I do this?

(Also - how can I set this so the default view is to have all the divs collapsed? The collapsible property allows all of the divs to be collapsed, instead of the default accordion functionality of always having one open, but it still initially displays with one div open; you then have to click that div's header to close it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible just repeat your Accordion markup, but rather than using an ID use a class.

```
<div class="accordion"> 
    <div> 
    <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3> 
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div> 
    </div> 
    <div> 
    <h3><a href="#">Second</a></h3> 
        <div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div> 
    </div> 
    <div> 
    <h3><a href="#">Third</a></h3> 
        <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Next change your jquery selector to use a class rather than an id.

$(".accordion").accordion({
   collapsible: true,
   header: "h3"
});

Comment: Thanks - it's the selectors thing I'm having the most difficulty getting a handle on. As to the second part of the question, is there a way to make all the divs collapsed by default?

Comment: Never mind - active:false before the collapsible:true did it.

Answer (score -2):

you can use random number for class in Java script and in HTML class

Comment: Random variable names, class names, or ids are never a good idea. In 2 years you may be looking at your code again, or someone else might, and they will not know what you're talking about. And numbers are some of the least descriptive names possible, unless combined with words, and even then it can just get too lengthy to make sense of.