# jquery UI accordion content div sliding up

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm very new to javascript & jquery - I'm using the jquery UI accordion found [here](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default)

What I'm trying to do is make the content slide up - So using the above link as an example, I want the content of section 1 to be above the title 'Section 1' after clicking on it. Not underneath as is the default mode.

There's plenty of accordion questions here, but none of them seem to deal with the content sliding up.

To give some context to this, I've created an archive page in WordPress and I'm trying to add 'Read more' to the content. I'm using the jquery ui accordion to show more content instead of being taken to the individual post (as that is what WordPress does by default).

The accordion is inside a query, so I have multiple accordions on the page. All work. I just can't figure out how to slide the content up, instead of down as is currently happening (i.e. default operation)

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var icons = {
      header: "icon-plus",
      activeHeader: "icon-minus"
    };
    $( ".accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true, active: false, icons: icons
    });

    $( "#toggle" ).button().click(function() {
      if ( $( ".accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons" ) ) {
        $( ".accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons", null );
      } else {
        $( ".accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons", icons );
      }
    }); 

    // Hover states on the static widgets
    $( "#dialog-link, #icons li" ).hover(
        function() {
            $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-hover" );
        },
        function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-hover" );
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

//EDIT

I added the above code as suggested. It's a little bit different because initially I couldn't get multiple accordions to work on the page. I found a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398285/jqueryui-accordion-can-i-have-more-than-one-per-page) that suggested changes to get multiple accordions to work on the page

Thanks

Comment: Please, post the code you're using and explain how and where you're applying it.

Comment: Are you using the default functionality like this: $( "#accordion" ).accordion();? To be able to collapse the content, you need to use this: $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true
    }); From the same [source](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible).